# Where is the source of segmentation fault : 11?

Tags: objective-c, struct, segmentation-fault, objective-c++

Please help, this is one of 3 faults i have in here, and i simply cannot find where they are : I know they are to do with my struct but i have no idea how to find them... Here is the first section of code with a fault in :

```
-(BOOL)detectCollisionBetweenEntityAtIndex:(int)index1 andEntityAtIndex:(int)index2
{
  if ((([entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityX >= [entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityX) && ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityX <= ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityX + [entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityWidth)) && ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityY >= [entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityY) && ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityY <= ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityY + [entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityLength))) || (([entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityX + [entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityWidth >= [entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityX) && ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityX + [entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityWidth <= ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityX + [entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityWidth)) && ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityY + [entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityLength  >= [entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityY) && ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityY + [entityArray objectAtIndex:index1].entityLength <= ([entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityY+ [entityArray objectAtIndex:index2].entityLength))))
  {
    return TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

entityArray is an NSMutable array populated with instances of a struct i made :

```
struct Entity
{
  int entityX;
  int entityY;
  int entityLength;
  int entityWidth;
  int entityType;
  int entitySpeed;
  bool isDead;
};
```

Comment: How are you inserting the data into your `entityArray `?

Comment: Like this : {
  Entity tmpEntity;
  tmpEntity.entityX = newEntityX;
  tmpEntity.entityY = newEntityY;
  tmpEntity.entityLength = newEntityLength;
  tmpEntity.entityWidth = newEntityWidth;
  tmpEntity.entityType = newEntityType;
  tmpEntity.entitySpeed = newEntitySpeed;
  
  int arrayAmount = [entityArray count];
  [entityArray insertObject:tmpEntity atIndex:arrayAmount];
  [tmpEntity release];
}

Comment: @DuskFall what you posted in your comment won't even compile.

Comment: I know, that was part of the problem, but I've fixed it now and have a new problem which I've already asked (how do I close this question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
    -(BOOL)detectCollisionBetweenEntityAtIndex:(int)index1 andEntityAtIndex:(int)index2
    {
    bool hasDetected = false;
      if (...)
      {
        hasDetected = TRUE;
      }
        else
      {
        hasDetected = FALSE;
      }
        return hasDetected ;
      }
```

Should sort it out!

Answer (score 3):

An `NSMutableArray` can only store Objective-C objects, not C structs. Wrap the entities in an `NSValue` object to store them in the array:

```
Entity entity;
// populate entity...

NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&entity objCType:@encode(struct Entity)];
[array addObject:value];
```

To get the value back, use `-[NSValue getValue:]`, like this:

```
NSValue *value = [array objectAtIndex:index];
Entity entity;
[value getValue:&entity];
```

Comment: How would i access this afterwards though?

Comment: Updated the answer. Also see the [`NSValue` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Invalid receiver type : Entity? What can i do now?

Comment: @DuskFall I've updated the answer. It should work now, I forgot to add the `struct` tag.